# how to favorite in Django

Tags: python, django

i am trying to make a favorites button, where the user simply clicks the button and the spot_information is Favorited for the user, and can also remove the favorite. i am wondering why when i click the favorite button it loads a white page with the "({'success': True})" at the very top.

also i am learning from Bucky Roberts GitHub and YouTube channel "theNewBoston", so i am sort of a beginner

## views.py

```
def favorite(request, spot_id):
spot = get_object_or_404(spot_information, pk=spot_id)
try:
    if spot.a_favourite:
        spot.a_favourite = False
    else:
        spot.a_favourite = True
    spot.save()
except (KeyError, spot.DoesNotExist):
    return JsonResponse({'success': False})
else:
    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

## urls.py

```
    # favorite
url(r'^(?P<spot_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
```

## my index html code

```
{% for spotinformation in all_spot_information %}
...
<a href="{% url 'cityinfo:favorite' spotinformation.id %}" class="btn-favorite">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" {% if spotinformation.afavorite %}active{% endif %}></span>&nbsp; Favorite
    </button>
</a>
...
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Gosh, so many things. When you click on the button, it's just like clicking on a link. So your browser goes to the address `spot_id/favorite/`, which returns the `JsonResponse` supplied by the view. If you want it to work the way it seems you do, you're going to have to use some client-side action, specifically Javascript and AJAX.

Comment: yeah sorry, i really suck at this, you have any useful links i can use, thanks for the help

Comment: Well, for what you have, you've got it working correctly, so good job! You're just missing the piece that allows the browser to communicate "behind the scenes". So you should search for help with "jQuery and ajax", and "change a button using JSON and AJAX" and see what you can get. It's not really a Django question anymore, because the Django is working. It's become a javascript/AJAX question.

Comment: thanks man, really appreciate the help. i see what you mean.